# Display number with 2 decimals like excel cell in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a web tool which makes some financial calculations and uses multiple numbers in inputs. Is there a way to display that number with only 2 decimals but behind when the app makes the math to use the entire number with all decimals? Something like excel cell which shows 2 decimals but behind the number has 10 decimals.

The problem is that if I round the numbers, the app gives incorrect values. It's just for display purpose to make it look neat and tidy.

Thx.

For ex:

Input real value: 8952340.66543023
Input display value: 8952340.67

Comment: Then round when displaying only?

Comment: Yes I want to round the number only when I display it in my app. But behind when the app runs I want to use the entire number

Comment: We don't know anything how you're using the value or where and how you're displaying it. Maybe you should post a bit of code to demonstrate the usage?

Comment: As you haven't posted a use-case, you're getting more or less unuseful answers only. If your question is taken literally, you want a user to enter a multi-digit decimal number to an input, and then display a fixed value in the same input element. That's possible, but it makes a lot of work. A simple way would be to mirror the form, and then submit the mirrored form instead of the displayed form. [Here's a parametrizable example](https://jsfiddle.net/hk3rj2bp/) of how to mirror a form. The example is not perfect, you've to add radio button and file/password inputs handling to the code too.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a general function which can round to any number of digits :

```
const roundTo =
    num =>
    digits =>
    Math.round(num * (10 ** digits)) / 10 ** digits

const num = 1234.8304

const roundToTwo = roundTo(num)(2) 

console.log(roundToTwo) // logs 1234.83
```

Where num is your number and digits is the n of digits after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **`toFixed(2)`** to reduce precision to two decimals.

but beware the return value is a string not a number

```js
let float = 1.23456789;
let fixed = float.toFixed(2);
console.log(fixed );

console.log(typeof(fixed))
```

Comment: From your answer, I will use the variable fixed to be displayed in my html file, but the variable float will be used in the actual math. For example input = float * 2 but in html I will display input.toFixed(2);

Comment: So basically for each input in my html file, in javascript I will have 2 variables. The real variable and the display variable

Comment: I don`t like that method toFixed because I had several problems with decimals. The way is wrong to round off. I prefer the other method.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const f1 = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
});

console.log("first -> ", f1.format(8952340.66543023));

const f2 = (n, d) => n.toLocaleString('en-US', {
   minimumFractionDigits: 2,      
   maximumFractionDigits: 2,
});

console.log("Second -> ", f2(8952340.66543023));
```

Try this code, and tell me.